# Access Azure Storage in an ASP.NET Core application using Connected Services

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-table-storage, asp.net-core-1.1

I try to follow the article [Access Azure Storage in an ASP.NET Core application using Connected Services](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/visualstudio/1328/visual-studio-connected-services-aspnet-core-azure-storage), under ASP.NET Core 1.1 in order to connect my web application to Azure Tables.

I created

```
public interface ITableRepositories
{
    void CreateRecord(Record record);
    List<Record> GetRecords();
    Record GetRecord(string key, string partitionKey = "record");
}
```

But the problem is that under ASP.NET Core and `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage` nuget I have no acces to the Syncronous methods.

So, by eg this code of the OperationService class:

```
public class TableClientOperationsService : ITableRepositories
{
    CloudStorageAccount storageAccount;
    CloudTableClient tableClient;
    IConfigurationRoot configs;

    public TableClientOperationsService(IConfigurationRoot c) {
        this.configs = c;
        var connStr =  this.configs.GetSection("MicrosoftAzureStorage:[...]");
        storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connStr.Value);
        tableClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();
        CloudTable table = tableClient.GetTableReference("Book");
        table.CreateIfNotExists();
    }
```

I am forced to do the Async variant of the connector:

```
public class TableClientOperationsService: ITableRepositories
{
    CloudStorageAccount storageAccount;        
    CloudTableClient tableClient;        

    public TableClientOperationsService(IOptions<AppSecrets> optionsAccessor) {
        string connectionString = optionsAccessor.Value.MyProjectTablesConnectionString;
        storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connectionString);
        tableClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();
        CloudTable table = tableClient.GetTableReference("Record");


        // ??? How to use the async method in constructor?
        var created = await table.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();
    }
}
```

So what should be the Async approach for this? Should I create a *static constructor* instead?

**PS.**

Also the CreateRecord "async" operation

from

```
public void CreateBook(Book bk)
{
    Random rnd = new Random();
    bk.BookId = rnd.Next(100);
    bk.RowKey = bk.BookId.ToString();
    bk.PartitionKey = bk.Publisher;
    CloudTable table = tableClient.GetTableReference("Book");
    TableOperation insertOperation = TableOperation.Insert(bk);
    table.Execute(insertOperation);
}
```

should be transformed in (?)

```
public void CreateRecord(Record record)
{
    // var rowKey = (DateTime.MaxValue.Ticks - DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks).ToString("d19");
    TableOperation insertOperation = TableOperation.Insert(record);
    this.RecordTable.ExecuteAsync(insertOperation).Wait();
}
```

Or rather in

```
public Task<TableResult> CreateRecord(Record record)
{
    TableOperation insertOperation = TableOperation.Insert(record);
    return this.RecordTable.ExecuteAsync(insertOperation);
}
```

Finally I did it like

```
public async Task<bool> CreateRecord(Record record)
{
    TableOperation insertOperation = TableOperation.Insert(record);
    await this.RecordTable.ExecuteAsync(insertOperation);
    return true;
}
```

also the

```
public Record GetRecord(string key, string partitionKey = "record")
{
    Record myRecord = null;
    TableOperation operation = TableOperation.Retrieve<Record>(partitionKey, key);
    // ?
    myRecord = recordTable.ExecuteAsync(operation).Result as Record;

}
```

Comment: For the `Create` I wouldn't return the TableResult since that's specific to the type of storage. Since you're implementing a repository, I would either return a boolean indicating success or the Result property of the TableResult class typed to the entity you're inserting. Mainly I would implement the repository to have async methods and call them accordingly.

Comment: Do you mean I should return a Task<bool> for the CreateAsync? Is a little bit hard for a beginner I didn't find a lot or articles about

Comment: as in the updated OP, I created `public async Task<bool> CreateRecord(Record record)` not sure if it OK, but at least it compiles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easy solution would be to just Wait() the async methods:

```
public class TableClientOperationsService: ITableRepositories
{
    CloudStorageAccount storageAccount;        
    CloudTableClient tableClient;        

    public TableClientOperationsService(IOptions<AppSecrets> optionsAccessor) 
    {
        string connectionString = optionsAccessor.Value.MyProjectTablesConnectionString;
        storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connectionString);
        tableClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();
        CloudTable table = tableClient.GetTableReference("Record");


        table.CreateIfNotExistsAsync().Wait();
    }
}
```

If you need the result of the async method, try Result:

```
var created = table.CreateIfNotExistsAsync().Result;
```

Personally I'm not a big fan of constructors with (too) much functionality in them. Especially if it's something that (relatively) might take a while like connecting to a StorageAccount. You could implement an `Initalize()` method that could be async. Or you could implement a lazy property that only creates the `CloudTable` (and everything needed to get there) the first time the property is used. This also enables you to re-use the `CloudTable` during the lifetime of your class.

This would look something like this:

```
private CloudTable _table;

private CloudTable Table
{
    get
    {
        if (_table == null)
        {
            var storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connectionString);
            var tableClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();
            _table = tableClient.GetTableReference("Record");

            _table.CreateIfNotExistsAsync().Wait();
        }

        return _table;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks... good idea... just the Wait() returns void... So probably no attribution here.

Comment: Thanks for the idea! Just could you take a look on the PS edit (`CreateRecord`), because it's the same question mainly...